# "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again" Sat4J

Tags: jar, java-native-interface, noclassdeffounderror, sat4j

I wrote a java programm using Sat4J and it works fine. Now I want to export it as a jar-File, but when I execute it, it allways says
"A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sat4j/specs/TimeoutException"

I don't have much experience with more then one package. So my structure is that I have one package with 4 classes I wrote and one package with 3 Sat4J classes. I don't even know if the error occurs because of sat4J or the different packages.

Does anyone have a clue what I can do? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example of your code. Where are you running the program?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all Sat4j classes (from org.sat4j.core.jar for instance) in your jar.

Your favorite IDE usually provides a way to automatically include all dependencies with your code in a single jar.